# Scrolling Title In UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I need a little help, I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

I have `UIViewController` class with `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` is used for horizontal `scrolling` (paging) of `UITableViewControllers`.

I would like to create effect like the `Twitter app` for iOS7 so that when the user swipe left or right, and the new `controller` is loaded, the title on the `UINavigationBar` changes.
When changing, title does not only appear but it looks like it's on the `scrollview` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this control (which I've used and found great) you can add it as a subView on your UINavigationBar https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Answer (score 0):

use titleView property of UIViewController to give your own custom view, and do animations on it using animateWithDuration Block.